# Nodes near coord overlapping...how to shift up

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

[image]

I am using nodes near coords but as you can see the values on the bottom are overlapping. I have tried placing them manually but that hasn't worked either...How to just shift up the nodes so they do not overlap with eachother or the line!?

Thank you!!!!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
compat=newest, 
height=0.4\textheight,
enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.3},
ymin=0,
xtick=data,
xtick={\empty},
ytick=data,
enlarge x limits = 0.5,
bar width=24pt,
title={},
symbolic x coords={0,5},
y axis line style={opacity=0},
yticklabels={\empty},
ytick style={draw=none},
axis on top,
major grid style=white,
nodes near coords
        ]

\addplot [red, line width=2pt]coordinates {(0,.1) (5,.83)};
\addplot [blue, line width=2pt]coordinates {(0,.12) (5,2.4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem, as the solution is going to depend on how you are drawing this.

Answer (score 10):

This is one possible solution.  Firstly, move `every node near coords` down a little bit via

```
every node near coord/.append style={yshift=-0.5cm}   % yshift can be adjusted
```

Then adds to the addplot[options] a particular `nodes near coords` (the blue one) via `raisebox`

```
nodes near coords=\raisebox{0.7cm}{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}  % 0.7 can be adjusted also.
```

The result is shown below

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
compat=newest, 
height=0.4\textheight,
enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.3},
ymin=0,
xtick=data,
xtick={\empty},
ytick=data,
enlarge x limits = 0.5,
bar width=24pt,
title={},
symbolic x coords={0,5},
y axis line style={opacity=0},
yticklabels={\empty},
ytick style={draw=none},
axis on top,
major grid style=white,
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={yshift=-0.5cm},
        ]
\addplot [red, line width=2pt] coordinates {(0,.1) (5,.83)};
\addplot [blue, line width=2pt,
nodes near coords=\raisebox{0.7cm}{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}
]
coordinates {(0,.12) (5,2.4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would manually place the nodes. Takes a bit more work, but I think the results are better:

[image]

### Notes:

- I added `clip=false` so that the text of the node was not cut off.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    compat=newest, 
    height=0.4\textheight,
    enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.3},
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data,
    xtick={\empty},
    ytick=data,
    enlarge x limits = 0.5,
    bar width=24pt,
    title={},
    symbolic x coords={0,5},
    y axis line style={opacity=0},
    yticklabels={\empty},
    ytick style={draw=none},
    axis on top,
    major grid style=white,
    %nodes near coords,
    clip=false
    ]

\addplot [red,  line width=2pt] coordinates {(0,.1) (5,.83)};
\addplot [blue, line width=2pt] coordinates {(0,.12) (5,2.4)};

\node [red,  below left] at (axis cs: 0,.1)  {0.1};
\node [red,  right     ] at (axis cs: 5,.95) {0.83};
\node [blue, above left] at (axis cs: 0,.12) {0.12};
\node [blue, right     ] at (axis cs: 5,2.4) {2.5};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```